Why do we use a single pointer rather than a double pointer to pass an array to a function?
Why not double pointer to take an array?
I'm having a bit of problem understanding why an array isn't passed as a double pointer (a pointer to a pointer) since the array name itself is a pointer (pointer to the first element of the array), just like if we pass a pointer as a function argument we need a double pointer to get it:
void d_func (uint8_t ** d_ptr, uint8_t **d_ptr2) /* pointer to a pointer as option to take a pointer as argument */
  {
   temp = *d_ptr;
   *d_ptr = *d_ptr2;
   *d_ptr2 = temp;
  }


void main (void)
  {
   uint8_t a = 1;
   uint8_t b = 5;
 
   uint8_t * p1 = &a;
   uint8_t * p2 = &b;

   d_func(&p1, &p2); /* pointer p1 and pointer p2 as arguments */
  } 

If this is how a function should take a pointer as argument (in a pointer to a pointer) why isn't an array the same? An array name is a pointer. If I print an array name it will give me the address of that array. If I print the address of the array (&array) it will show the same as the preview one but pointing to the whole array. So what I'm not understanding is why we pass arrays as single pointer arguments and not pointers to a pointers.
void array_func (uint8_t * array) /* why a pointer not a pointer to a pointer ??? */
   {
    printf("array element :%d \n", array[0]);
   }

void main (void)
   {
    uint8_t mya_arr[3] = {1,2,3};
    array_func(my_arr);
   }

Why isn't the array_func like this?
void array_func (uint8_t ** array)
   {
    printf("array element :%d \n", array[0]);
   }


Counter question, why should we add a layer of indirection that we don't need and that will perform worse by default? If you want to or if it fits your usecase, you can still use a double indirection.

Remember that & is a pointer-to operator If you create a pointer to a pointer (like &p1)  then the argument-type must be a pointer to a pointer. But for arrays, you have to remember that it will decay to a pointer to its first element, so my_arr is the same as &my_arr[0]. That is, you only have a single pointer to a single element. And in your case it's a pointer to an uint8_t value.

In short, the two examples are not equivalent. For them to be equivalent you should have uint8_t *p1 = my_arr; and use &p1 to call the function. But then you have a pointer to a pointer to the first element, which you need to dereference to get a pointer to the actual element: (*array)[0].

The misunderstanding seems to be here: "An array name is a pointer." It is not, so the conclusions don't follow.

Arrays are not pointers.  Under most circumstances, array expressions are converted to pointer expressions whose value is the address of the first element of the array.  No pointer is actually stored anywhere.  The call array_func(my_arr) is implicitly converted to something equivalent to array_func(&my_arr[0]).  When you pass an array expression as an argument, what the function actually receives is a pointer to the first element.
